# how to add viral friend invitations like foursquare and other apps to my iPhone a

Tags: ios

Wondering if there is some open source code for adding "invite your friends" functionality to your IOS apps. Attaching an image from foursquare, but I have seen this in many other apps too.

[image: Foursquare Example]